# How to get Julia executable path in vscode on Mac

Tags: visual-studio-code, julia

The message:

***Could not start the julia language server. Make sure the configuration setting julia.executablePath points to the julia binary.***

Pops up when trying to install run Julia in vscode on my Mac. I tried

**Macintosh HD/Applications/Julia-1.7.app**

But this didn't work and gives the same error

Comment: Try entering `whereis julia` in the terminal and then copy its executable path

Answer (score 4):

So after messing around some more it seems that you have to go all the way to the inner executable to get it to work.

I wanted to post the answer in case anyone else has this problem in the future.

**Solution:**

Right click on the julia application in finder and click 'Show package contents' from there this is the overall path i used as the vscode julia path:

***/Applications/Julia-1.7.app/Contents/Resources/julia/bin/julia***

Comment: Nice. If you get an error after setting the path to executable, try a restart: worked for me. YMMV.